# How to return to MainActivity from MapIntent

Tags: android, android-studio

I implemented a `mapIntent` for one of my activities and I am wondering how do I go back to the `MainActivity` from the google maps intent? Because, I have to click back a few times to return to a blank page before I go to the `MainActivity`.

Here is my code for the `Activity` with the `mapIntent`.

```
public class ViewLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_location);

        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=hospitals");
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        startActivity(mapIntent);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you've starting your `ViewLocationActivity` first from your `MainActivity` and then starting another `Activity` with your `mapIntent`. Why don't you just start the `mapIntent` from your `MainActivity`?

```
// Put this in your MainActivity where you started `ViewLocationActivity`
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=hospitals");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your MapActivity:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
```